# Read values from non-root web.config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, global-asax, directory, directory-structure

My site is structured in this way:

- **Root Directory**

  - **Arcade**

    - default.aspx
    - web.config
  - default.aspx
  - web.config

I have a method `Method1()` which accesses:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Total_Unique_Plays_Required_For_High_Score_Board"]
```

This value exists in the `root/Arcade/Web.config` file but not in the `root/web.config` file.

When I execute `Method1()` from a page in the `/arcade` directory it works fine.  However, when I execute this method as a timed event from `global.asax` it searches for the value in the root `web.config` file and throws a `System.NullException`.

Does anyone know how I can specify to search for the value in the `root/arcade/web.config` file and not the `root/web.config` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the web.config file first.

So calling this will load your child file; notice you give the path to the folder containing the web.config, not the actual config file.

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Arcade");
```

You can now get your values, like:

```
string MyValue  = config.AppSettings.Settings["MySetting"].Value;
```

You can also get the list of app settings by calling:

```
KeyValueConfigurationCollection appSettings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
```